# Login using HTMLunit redirects to goolge capcha

Tags: java, authentication, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to login to https://www.jvzoo.com/ using HTMLunit 2.31. 
But It shows google captcha. 
But if I try to login in through browser it works fine.
I have added all the parameters needed for request.

**Code snippet:**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "https://www.jvzoo.com/auth/login";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    try {
        WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(new URL(url), HttpMethod.POST);
             webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Accept", "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Host", "www.jvzoo.com");
        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Referer", "https://www.jvzoo.com/auth/login");
        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; r…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat smt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss");
        String format = smt.format(date);

        webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Cookie", "__cfduid=d042d9103fb79ed922e5ac17dac50f45a1532320289;_ga=GA1.2.1331177163.1532322753"
                + ";_gid=GA1.2.810982780.1532322753;announcement_cookie=" + format + ";cookieconsent_status=allow"
                + ";csrf_protected=64c6852ecf1bc1720e3e83cafc1b4618;"
                + "jvzsession=6lAUaU8wUPAbdXF9alRljftFv3aytU05vTVRm22yNrWvZNsjxsyYNfGEQF2xx4irKm/DALWU/pQZ1fRgjv7HwQ==");
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new NameValuePair("csrf_protected", "64c6852ecf1bc1720e3e83cafc1b4618"));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("forward", ""));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("login", username));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("remember", "1"));
        webRequest.setRequestParameters(params);

        Page page = webClient.getPage(webRequest);
        WebResponse webResponse = page.getWebResponse();

        HtmlPage htmlpage = HTMLParser.parseHtml(webResponse, webClient.getCurrentWindow());
        System.out.println("doc:" + htmlpage.asXml());
        System.out.println("Getting dashboard..");
        //HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.jvzoo.com/dashboard");
        //System.out.println("doc:" + page1.asXml());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you completely miss the point of the HtmlUnit API. Please have a look at the second sample (Submitting a form) at the [HtmlUnit Getting Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) page. Usually there is no need to build your own web request and definitely no need to parse the response yourself.

And as second advice, please do not disable javascript; do it only if your are really really sure you don't need it.

If this does not help, you can try to send me test credentials via mail and i will have a look.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that just by submitting form using htmlunit , I was able to login.

Comment: I have  voted but it says my vote wont be shown until I have 15 reputations.